# HTML Formatting in VB RichTextBox

Tags: html, vb.net, formatting

Is it possible to format text in a richtextbox for HTML?

What I mean by that is text statements will appear blue, for example and expressions might appear green.

Is there a special component that I need or can I just do it with simple code?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend go with some HTML Editor instead of RTE